# Creating a Standalone Application in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, portable-executable

I had come upon an [article about .Net in Linux](https://dzone.com/refcardz/net-on-linux) and am interested in creating a standalone application that works without needing to install .Net Core, and works even on Mac and Linux.

Is that also applicable to PowerShell?

Also if you have modules that you get from installed programs, say VMWare PowerCLI, which you use in the application logic, how would you make it so you extract those and make those portable as well?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you compile a DLL instead of an executable and then use their runtime to load local libraries instead of looking for .Net core to be installed.  That implies that this approach works for apps that you are going to compile, such as C#, but not for PowerShell scripts.  Same would apply for the VMWare apps.